# Angularjs dyanamically added directive scope issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have running example here,

[Angularjs Circle Directory](http://plnkr.co/edit/5IPRZVoD0hH8cUJHWEEq?p=preview)

I have directory which is added dynamically upon clicking button. Once the circle directory is added, I am increasing the counter inside circle directory. But the problem here is all the directory are updated with same value, which is not correct.

please let me know, how can I increase the counter of each directory individually.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are going for here but you use `count` and `counter` inconsistently. That accounts for most of the errors that I can see. Are you asking to isolate the scope for the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3VqZdfXqqM6Bh9xhy8CM?p=preview)

Ok you know a little generally about JavaScript, but there's a whole culture to how Angular would approach this.

Your main issue is that you're dynamically adding an element outside of Angular and its data, when semantically you're just trying to add and remove the number of circles on a screen. For that, you can use an `ng-repeat` on your `circel` directive. Simple.

A few related fixes

- Instead of `$(document).ready({ //running bindings })`, try using `ng-click` or related Angular directives
- Consider keeping indentation clean
- You can use Angular's `$index` instead of incrementing a window scope variable
- Semantically, the `scope.add` and `scope.remove` functions aren't properties of the circle, they're control buttons outside of the circle. Try moving those to a controller scope, no not a directive controller, an app controller.
- Any time you want each directive unit to have its own scope, declare `{ scope: true }` in the directive return object, or look at individually declaring each scope property, e.g. `{ scope: { myProp: '=' } }`
- On adding and removing: The Angular way is very, very rarely to append/prepend elements like you're doing mixing jQuery with Angular; instead the `ng-repeat` will take care of adding/removing DOM elements, which also obeys "single source of truth" methods.
- I think you mean "Directive" not "Directory"

Comment: I didnot got this point, "Your main issue is that you're dynamically adding an element outside of Angular and its data". While adding I am using angularjs $compile. that means directive is converted into angularjs, so it is angularjs scope only right?

Comment: Yes, `$compile` searches DOM elements for directives. But DOM adding/subtracting isn't typically handled outside of Angular, because the DOM elements should be directly representative of the data inside the Angular controller. By adding new DOM elements via jQuery (or vanilla JS) you are adding new DOM elements outside of Angular data. It's does not adhere to [single source of truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) patterns.